# How can I populate a list box from another list box using instr, and mid to make the finished product look a certain way?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I tried looking for this for hours and couldn't find what I was looking for. I am very new to programming and still don't know how to manipulate data too well...

**What I am trying to do is:**

there are 4 forms that i am currently working with. Call them **frm1, frm2, frm3, frm4**. I am trying to create a finished product in frm4 from the information provided in the other 3 forms. I need the data to be printed in this `order line = "0000 ---- --- --- --- --- --- ---".` I currently have the `first two lines "0000 ----"` how I want them. The problem that I am having is that these `"--- --- --- --- --- --- ---"` lines are going to be populated from another form frm3.lst3.items and when I bring the line over and cut the the first two numbers off each item in the list I am only able to insert them into the first  three dashes of the **"line"** and can not insert them  across.

**frm4.lst4 looks like this:**

```
"0000 aaaa --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"              
"0000 bbbb --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"           
"0000 cccc --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"           
"0000 dddd --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"          
"0000 eeee --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"                        
"0000 ffff --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"              
"0000 gggg --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"                  
"0000 hhhh --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"
```

**frm3.lst3**

```
1 aaaa                                                
2 dddd                                                   
3 aaaa                                                   
4 zzzz                                                
5 aaaa                                         
6 aaaa                                      
7 aaaa                                               
8 aaaa                                                
9 aaaa
```

I need to match the letters in the frm3 with the letter in frm4 and add the number with dashes into the `"---"` making it look like this `"0000 aaaa 001 003 005 006 007 008 009".`

```
' already found strCode and that = aaaa                      
Dim possition As String                                
        For Each strCode In lstTeamResults.Items                        
            strLine = "0000 ---- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"                      
            Mid(strLine, 5, 4) = strCode
```

' i know that instr gives the int location of the next available "---". Just dont know how to use it in a comand that would populate the next open `"---"` with proper code..

```
        InStr(10, strLine, "---")

        For Each item In frmRM3.lst3.Items

            possition = item
            ' this code returns the number 1, 2, 3....
            intPossition = InStr(item, " ")
            possition = Trim(Mid(possition, 1, intPossition - 1))
        Next


    Next
   lst4.items.add(strLine)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, it's self-contained I think, you should be learning how to use Substring and IndexOf instead of those functions anyway.

```
        Dim strLine As String = "0000 ---- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"


        Mid(strLine, 6, 4) = strCode

        For Each item As String In ListBox2.Items

            possition = item
            ' this code returns the number 1, 2, 3....
            intPossition = InStr(item, " ")
            Dim lineNumber As String
            lineNumber = Mid(item, 1, intPossition - 1)
            Dim code As String
            code = Mid(item, intPossition + 1, 4)
            If strCode = code Then
                'Position of next available dashes
                Dim availablePosition As Integer
                availablePosition = InStr(1, strLine, "---")
                If availablePosition <> 0 Then
                    'Pad number with zeros
                    Dim numberPaddedWithZeros As String
                    numberPaddedWithZeros = "000" & lineNumber
                    numberPaddedWithZeros = Mid(numberPaddedWithZeros, Len(numberPaddedWithZeros) - 3 + 1, 3)

                    'Replace available positions
                    Mid(strLine, availablePosition, 3) = numberPaddedWithZeros
                End If
            End If

        Next
        ListBox1.Items.Add(strLine)
```

Comment: Thank you Civa for cleaning up my paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. The code you gave me helped me get one line of code. Maybe I ruined it when I messed with it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Daniel Victoria for your help with this. I changed the code you gave me to fit my program. Thought it would have been too long if I posted the actual problem and it may have not been clear enough. This is what I have so far:

' This code add the 4 characters that go on the 4 dashes after the 0000 so that the following code and use that to add the numbers to the "--- --- --- --- --- --- ---"

```
Private Sub btnCalculateResults_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateResults.Click
    Dim intPossition As Integer
    Dim strLine As String = ""
    Dim strSchoolCode As String


    strLine = "0000 ---- --- --- --- --- ---  --- ---"
    strSchoolCode = ""
    lstTeamResults.Items.Clear()


    For Each team As String In frmRM1000.lstTeam.Items
        strSchoolCode = team
        intPossition = InStr(1, strSchoolCode, "|")
        strSchoolCode = Trim(Mid(strSchoolCode, 1, intPossition - 1))

        strLine = "0000  ---- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"
        Mid(strLine, 6, 4) = strSchoolCode

        lstTeamResults.Items.Add(strLine)
    Next
```

'This is the code which Daniel helped me fix
'now I just need to loop this code so it populates the rest of the fields
'there is a total of 9 rows that need to be populated:

"0000 AUBH --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"
"0000 GSH- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"
"0000 NBHS --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"
"0000 OHXS --- --- --- --- --- --- ---" 'THIS ONE DIPLICATE AND NEEDS TO GO
"0000 OHXS 001 002 003 004 005 006 007"  'THIS ONE POPULATED WELL
"0000 QRHS --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"
"0000 WBCH --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"
"0000 WDHS --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"
"0000 WHS- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"
"0000 WSHS --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"

'This is the code for the above output:

Dim strLine1 As String = "0000 ---- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---"
        Dim possition As String
        Dim lineNumber As String

```
    Mid(strLine, 6, 4) = strSchoolCode
    'For Each item In
    '    lineNumber = item

    'Next

    For Each runner As String In frmRM3000.lstSyncTimeBibs.Items 'lstTeamResults.Item

        possition = runner
        ' this code returns the runner possiton number 1, 2, 3....
        intPossition = InStr(runner, " ")


        lineNumber = Mid(runner, 1, intPossition - 1)
        Dim code As String
        code = Mid(strLine, 6, 4)
        If strSchoolCode = code Then
            'Position of next available dashes
            Dim availablePosition As Integer
            availablePosition = InStr(1, strLine, "---")
            If availablePosition <> 0 Then
                'Pad number with zeros
                Dim numberPaddedWithZeros As String
                numberPaddedWithZeros = "00" & lineNumber
                numberPaddedWithZeros = Mid(numberPaddedWithZeros, Len(numberPaddedWithZeros) - 3 + 1, 3)

                'Replace available positions
                Mid(strLine, availablePosition, 3) = numberPaddedWithZeros
            End If
        End If

    Next
    lstTeamResults.Items.Add(strLine)
```

This does add the code to the lines "--- --- --- --- --- --- ---" but it only adds it to one line of the code and does it on the 5th line. I need it to do it for all the line. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I know that it is inserting the code into the 5 field because that's is where it found the line code it was looking for. How do I get it to go to the next strSchoolCode after it it done filling that line?